# Ajax request showing error

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-redux, form-data

I am getting an error on ajax call - **"No handler found for "undefined"**. Attached the screenshot in the following. I'm running this on react-redux application.

[image]

[image]

Had any of you guys faced the same issue? Any help? The code is given in the following:

```
export function updateBrandAdmin(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var brand_admin_data = data;
  var updateUrl = `<url for ajax request>`;

  return function(dispatch) {
    var brandAdminData = new FormData();

    //append description
    if(data.description && (data.description != "")) {
      brandAdminData.append("description", brand_admin_data.description);
    }

    //append banner name
    if(brand_admin_data.brand_name && (brand_admin_data.brand_name != "")) {
      brandAdminData.append("name", brand_admin_data.brand_name);
    }

    //append products
    if (brand_admin_data.productids && brand_admin_data.productids.length > 0) {
      for(var j=0; j < brand_admin_data.productids.length; j++) {
        brandAdminData.append("products_ids[]", brand_admin_data.productids[j]);
      }
    }

    //append logo
    //The issue was here when I wasn't giving this check
    if (brand_admin_data.logoAttribute.files[0]) {
      brandAdminData.append("logo", brand_admin_data.logoAttribute.files[0]);
    }

    //append banner attributes
    if (brand_admin_data.banners_attributes) {
      // formData.append("video_attributes[]", null);
      // if(brand_admin_data.banners_attributes.length > 0) {
        // for(var i=0; i < brand_admin_data.banners_attributes.length; i++) {
      brandAdminData.append("banners_attributes[]", brand_admin_data.banners_attributes[0].files[0]);
        // }
      // }
    }

    // console.log(data);
    // console.log(updateUrl);

    $.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: updateUrl,
      data: brandAdminData,
      headers: getToken(),
      success: function(resp, status) {
        console.log(resp);
      },
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      timeout: 60000
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the API which you called has right URL? and are you sure you can access the "PUT" AJAX type?

Comment: Shared another screenshot from postman @FadhlyPermata

Comment: Did you know if [PUT requests are idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/PUT)?

Comment: yes I know. But whats the issue with that ? @FadhlyPermata

Comment: this seems to be a custom message from your server- that's where you should investigate the issue

Comment: While sending request from postman, its not giving the msg but when sending the request by ajax call its giving showing this msg.

Comment: Okay.. It's solved.. Thanks